# construct conditional SQL statement with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

what is the best way to construct an SQL statement with PDO when it depends on whether some PHP variable are set?

Here is an example;

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table ";

if($variable1 != "") {  $query = $query . "WHERE variable1 = :variable1";   }                   
if($variable2 != "") {  $query = $query . " AND variable2 = :variable2";    }                   

$query -> execute(array(':variable1' => $variable1, ':variable2' => $variable2));
```

I have a lot of these `if` statements and when binding the variables to the query I don't want to go through all these `if` statements again.

Is there an easier way to construct an SQL statement with such if/else conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an array to contain each part of the where... as a match occurs, add the resulting statement to the array. After all are evaluated, implode, separating with " AND " and concatenate onto $query.

```
$arrWhere = array();
$assWhere = array();

if($variable1 != "") {
    $arrWhere[] = "variable1 = :variable1";
    $assWhere[":variable1"] = $variable1;
}
if($variable2 != "") {
    $arrWhere[] = "variable2 = :variable2";
    $assWhere[":variable2"] = $variable2;
}
if($variable3 != "") {
    $arrWhere[] = "variable3 = :variable3";
    $assWhere[":variable3"] = $variable3;
}

$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . implode ( " AND " , $arrWhere );

$query -> execute($assWhere);
```

Comment: yes, that would probably be more elegant to construct the query – but how do I then know what I need to bind in the execute statement?

Comment: Not 100% on this, but looks like execute take associative array... see code in edited Answer.

Comment: This will work most of the time, but the `WHERE` clause should be added conditionally, since it's possible that none of `variableN` contains a value.

Comment: I completely agree with zero... actually $query never need be set if count($arrWhere)<1... didn't add to the answer as SO doesn't encourage completing code for inquirers beyond answering the question posted.